# How to copy a file in my local computer to the remote virtual machine?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, putty

Is there easily way to copy a file from local computer to a virtual machine? I want to copy a file in my local computer which path is "C:/users/local/data.txt" to a virtual machine. I am new for the JVM and linux system, so I want to find a useful method to copy it.

Additional Info: I am using a Windows 10 machine. I connected to a virtual machine through *putty*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here to use **FileZilla** to manipulate the file, it's easy to do the copy or delete work.

Also it did not need only to use putty, others interface also work in JVM

Here is the link: https://filezilla-project.org/

Remember download the client version, after installment, you can use it:

[image: Picture 1]

As I use red link circled button, you can click it to type your IP, name, etc.
Remember you need to choose **SFTP** in the red circled in below picture:

[image: Picture 2]

After click OK, then type the password, you can manipulate the file in it,

the left part in Picture 1 shows the files in current local computer and the right part in Picture 1 shows the file in JVM.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: That's great! +1